# Sync BlackBerry persistent data with desktop to survive device transfers and OS upgrades

Tags: blackberry

If a BlackBerry application stores data in the persistent store, that data typically gets erased when the user performs a data transfer to a new device (using RIM's desktop software), or when the user performs an OS upgrade on the device.

I believe the RIM api does provide facilities for making an application adhere to whatever rules it needs to in order for its persisted data to be backed up and restored properly during upgrades and transfers. But the available documentation doesn't explore this very well.

What is the proper way to make your BlackBerry app behave properly during data backups and transfers?

RIM OS 4.1+

Comment: I have the same problem - I need to preserve my application persistent data across an OS update. One of my colleagues mentioned that we would need to save our data to a database to make it persist across an OS update, but I'm afraid I haven't looked into it more than that yet.

Answer (score 1):

To do it the way you mentioned you could look at [this](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/Backing_up_data_1219851_11.jsp) and use the synchronization API to include it in a backup.

OR

Save it to a flat file located on the [SD card](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/picker/FilePicker.html) if the user has it, or invoke an [email](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/blackberry/api/mail/package-summary.html) and allow the user to send that flat file to himself (you can encode it if it has sensitive information. maybe... Base64 and encrypted). Write a class that allows a user to import "settings" from a file. Use the native file picker if its saved on SD card or if its in an email, pre-populate that email with the location the user should save the attachment.